# vcpkg C++ wxWidgets 3.1.6 , running application has missing dll "pcre2-16.dll"

Tags: wxwidgets, vcpkg

I have recently **upgraded** from **wxWidgets 3.1.5** to **wxWidgets 3.1.6** with vcpkg. My **application** used to run fine with **version 3.1.5**. When I try to run my **application** with **wxWidgets 3.1.6** I get a **missing dll** error message :

[image]

All I did was :

```
vcpkg install wxwidgets:x64-windows

vcpkg integrate install
```

I even tried to install it again , but it still didn't work.

I am using the **wxWidgets 3.1.6** dll.

**Thank you**

Comment: is the file in question exist anywhere on the system?

Comment: Actually yes !!?!! After reading this comment, I searched through the vcpkg files and found it in "installed\x64-windows\bin". Am I just supposed to copy the dll file to my application folder myself?? I am pretty sure Visual Studio is supposed to do for me ? Also Is this a bug in vcpkg ?

Comment: Copying the dll file into my app directory worked. But I want an answer why Visual Studio/vcpkg didn't copy the dependencies to the right place.

Comment: MSVC is not suppose to - its not its job. You can make it its job by adding the additional target that will be executed at the end of the build but by default - its on you.